# How can I fix the image to be responsive with different screen sizes?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

Here's the page that I'm trying to fix:
http://imvbusiness.com/home/

Some parts of it are adjusting properly, but some other parts are not.

The problems I have are:

1. when I shrink the browser width, some of the images don't shrink according to the screen size. How can I make all the images to be adjusted at the same time when the screen size is reduced?
2. for the images that shrink, they shrink differently on different browsers. On Firefox, the images only reduce in width, how do I make it to be adjusted proportionally? The same images on Chrome are adjusted properly, but it adds additional space on top and below the images. How can I make it to reduce the size of the image without adding extra spaces? How I can make the images behave the same on all the browsers?
3. for the menu bar on top of the page, how can I make it so that it'll start with 1 line, then 2 lines when the screen wide is reduced, and then 3 lines, and so on until at the end, 1 menu item per line?

   ```
   <div id="page" class="bg_gray container">
       <img src="images/ivan-quote-1-960x300.jpg" style="max-width:100%; height:auto; margin:auto;" />
   </div>
   ```

and the css:

```
.bg_gray
{
    background-color: #3F3F3F;
}

.container
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Try using percentages instead of pixels in adjusting your images in CSS3 , because 2px on a tablet would be way more than 2px on a phone and 2px on a computer screen would me much greater than 2px on a tablet..